# how to add Union in Sequelize js on existing WHERE condition?

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

**The where condition in seqlelize with node below**
*WHERE A->*

```
where: {
            [Op.or]: [{
                ownerid: {
                    [Op.in]: rows.map(row => row.ownerid),
                }
            }, {
                ownerid: {
                    [Op.notIn]: rows.map(row => row.ownerid),
                },
             shop: 1
            }]
        }
```

**will generate**

```
select *
    from users 
    WHERE (ownerId in ('12', '166') )  or    
        (ownerId not IN ('12','166')  and shop = 1 )
```

**in postgresql**

**I want to add another condition to where** ( UNION condition )to this where CONDITION : **LIKE  BELOW GIVEN**

WHERE B->

```
where: {
        ownerid: {
                    [Op.eq]: 13 
                }
             shop: 1
        }
```

I want to generate

```
(
    select *
    from users
    where ownerId = 13 and shop = 1
)
union
(
    select *
    from users 
    WHERE (ownerId in ('12', '166') and `delete` is null)  or    
        (ownerId not IN ('12','166')  and shop = 1 and `delete` is null)
)
```

DESIRED RESULT

```
where: {
            [Op.or]: [{
                ownerid: {
                    [Op.in]: rows.map(row => row.ownerid),
                }
            }, {
                ownerid: {
                    [Op.notIn]: rows.map(row => row.ownerid),
                },
             shop: 1
            }]
        }
```

**PLUS**

```
where: { ownerid: { [Op.eq]: 13 } shop: 1 }
```

**TO CREATE**

**

```
(
        select *
        from users
        where ownerId = 13 and shop = 1
    )
    union
    (
        select *
        from users 
        WHERE (ownerId in ('12', '166') and `delete` is null)  or    
            (ownerId not IN ('12','166')  and shop = 1 and `delete` is null)
    )
```

**

PS : ID 13 is dynamic , the ownwer id 13 can change to another numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use `union` if you want to join records from the same table but only with different conditions. You can just join them by `OR`.
The SQL might look like this:

```sql
select *
from users 
WHERE (ownerId in ('12', '166') and `delete` is null)  or    
  (ownerId not IN ('12','166')  and shop = 1 and `delete` is null) or
  (ownerId = 13 and shop = 1)
```

Sequelize query condition might look like this:

```js
where: {
  [Op.or]: [{
    ownerid: {
      [Op.in]: rows.map(row => row.ownerid),
    }
  }, {
    ownerid: {
      [Op.notIn]: rows.map(row => row.ownerid),
    },
    shop: 1
  }, {
    ownerid: 13,
    shop: 1
  }]
}
```

Comment: Thank you this is right way. Is there any way I can get all the users with owner id 13 first, and then the rest ? like ={all the users with owner id 13.....rest of the users with other owner ids}

Comment: What do you mean by `first`? Sorting records so users with a given id should be first?

Comment: Thank you for reply. You are right. That is what i literally what, no more and no less.

Comment: `order: [[Sequelize.literal('(ownerId = $ownerId)'), 'DESC']]` and `bind: { ownerId: 13 }`

Comment: RE: "there is no need..." that not always true. In the case where a query uses a fulltext MATCH clause in MySql for example, using OR instead of UNION will cause it to skip using the fulltext index and thus greatly harm performance